# Clarification about base in Banach space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

A basic sequence in a Banach space is a subset $\{x_n\}$ so that every point in the closed linear span of the $\{x_n\}$ has a unique representation of the form $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx_n$

If $\{x_n\}$ is a linearly independent set, does every point in the closed linear span have some representation in the above form? I.e. is uniqueness all that need be checked

Comment: A word of caution: linear independence does not guarantee uniqueness of infinite sums, only finite sums.

Answer (score 1):

First of all an element in the closed linear span of a linearly in dependent set $(x_n)$ need not have an expansion of the form $\sum a_nx_n$ and secondly the representations, when  it exist, need not be unique.

As example consider the functions $1,z,z^{2},...$. Functions that have a series expansion are analytic functions but functions in the closed span are continuous functions. [I am being deliberately vague. Can you make this precise?

Comment: I am aware it need not be unique, but it is not to clear to me why it must exist, which was my question

Comment: @Analysis  I have added a few lines to my answer.